# NSSet setByAddingObject: object cannot be nil

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to Xcode.  I have a series of sports apps that are designed to easily switch out the data for different teams.  The data is in html.  To create an app for a new team, I duplicate the parent app, rename it, and switch out the data files.  The new app crashes when I press a button.  I get the following response:

**Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '** -[NSSet setByAddingObject:]: object cannot be nil'*

When I run an Exception Breakpoint, it leads me to this line:

**removable = [removable setByAddingObject:oteam];**

I am confused because this line of code is not an issue in the parent app at all.  The 2 apps' code looks identical, but the offspring app crashes.  Any ideas?

Comment: The error message tell you exactly the problem - "object cannot be nil". The object being oteam.

Comment: Your problem can't be diagnosed unless you post more of your code that is relevant to this. Perhaps also posting your html that you're using. Just a guess would be that the format of the data that you're dealing with is different. The error is stating that whatever you're passing to `setByAddingObject:` is `nil`, so look at why it would be `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message indicates that `oteam` is `nil`.
Objective-C collections
(arrays, dictionaries, sets) cannot hold `nil` elements, therefore

```
[removable setByAddingObject:oteam];
```

crashes if `oteam == nil`.